# Binary size limit for iPhone, iPad and for Univercel app

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod

Can you people let me know what is the application binary size limit for iPhone, iPad and for Univercel app....

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1605342) they state the limit is 2 gigs.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any limit, but if you go over 20MB, users won't be able to download it using 3G (has to be wireless)